# VB.NET I'm trying to generate a sequence number in Mysql and Show my return query to datagridview ERROR

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Hello  I'm trying to generate a sequence number in Mysql and it work but when i try my return query to vb.net code  I got an error saying

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Fatal error encountered during command execution.' Inner Exception MysqlException:Parameter '@row' must be defined.

I try creating row in Datatable but its still an error

```
 If ComboBox2.Text = "All" Then
        Dim query As String = "SET @row := 0;
                SELECT  @row := @row + 1 as row,  concat( firstname, ' ', mname, ' ', lastname ) AS Fullname, barangay as Barangay, nature_of_work as 'Status', level 'Year Level', date(member_since) as 'Date Registered', login_count as 'Number Of Visit' 
                        FROM blhtraining.userinfo  t, (SELECT @row := 0)  r
                         Where 
                         date(member_since) BETWEEN  '" & DateTimePicker4.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-M-d") & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker3.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-M-d") & "'
                         AND login_count >=  '" & TextBox1.Text & "' 
                         Order by Fullname"
        Dim regular_user_table As New DataTable()
        Dim regular_user_adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, mycon)
        regular_user_adapter.Fill(regular_user_table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = regular_user_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay now i found a solution here https://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html

You connection should be like this
Dim mycon As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=blhtraining;Uid=root;Allow User Variables=True")